# Ontograf protege is not showing individuals in case of joined ontology

Tags: java, sparql, semantic-web, owl, protege

First of all, it has been working for the last 4 months, but now **when I need to write the report** it stopped.

When i have one ontology with instances, the Ontograf shows the individuals, but when i create a new ontology and load another ontology, the ontograf doesn't show the individuals from the other ontology.

i tried repeating everything from scratch, i tried to make each ontology just one class and one individuals, but i sitll have the problem, i installed protege `Protege-5.0.0-beta-24` and `Protege-5.0.0-beta-23` and `Protege-5.0.0-beta-21` and `Protege-5.0.0-beta-17` but still have the same problem (in the past i was working with Protege-5.0.0-beta-23 and it was working)

just yesterday everythign was fine, today nothing is working,

#### Update

I uploaded a minimum example to show you the problem:

the file contains three ontologies, the first.ttl has one class and one instances, the second.ttl has one class, the third join them together and make the class of the first as a sub class of the second. in this joined ontology i can't see the instances that is in first.ttl using ontograf

http://www.mediafire.com/download/6rr3xwb196mxab1/StackoverflowMinimumExample.zip

Comment: please help, i worked hard for the problem and now i am writing the report, if this doesn't work, it is like i didn't work. appreciate it guys

Comment: This is funny, nobody helped you after 1h on Friday evening...and moreover, do you know that there is a Protege mailing list?

Comment: Maybe Ontograf does not consider imported axioms? It's also not clear how you import the other ontology. Is it shown correctly in Protege?

Comment: Moreover, this is definitely the wrong platform as you're asking nothing code related but a tool specific question. And last but not least, why do you tag all your questions with `sparql`? I don't see here any relationship to nor usage of SPARQL.

Comment: So what *did* change between the time it was working and now?  Can't you just roll back to the older version?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I didn't change anything at all, i still have the problem

Comment: @AKSW i import using protege, there is an import button, i click, then they give me 4 options, i select import from a file on local desk and i select the path to it

Comment: @ania you said "First of all, it has been working for the last 4 months,"  if it's not working now, then *something* is different from the last time that it worked.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor well i sware i didn't do anything, i just updated my itunes, that is the only thing i did really,

Comment: If you try with your data files from,  say,  three weeks ago,  what happens?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor the same thing, instances not shown, would you like to make two ontologies each one has just one class and one instances and i join them in a third ontology and i put the three ontologies in the question so you stack users can test on their machines ?

Comment: A reproducible test case would certainly make this a more answerable question.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor okay I will provide one, in like an hour

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I've just uploaded my question and added the minimum example, could you check please if you have time ?

Comment: @AKSW in a Google search, I've found this http://protege.stanford.edu/support.php , which sounds like a page to subscribe not to ask about problems. I think you meant another page, right? if yes, what it is please?

Comment: @Ania that's the right page. You subscribe to the mailing list and then you can post messages to it, just like the jena users mailing lists. These are free and open [discussion mailing lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_mailing_list#Discussion_list), not something that you have to pay for. Subscription only ensures that it doesn't get full of spam.

Comment: On the page that you linked to, it says, "Get free support for all of your Protégé questions via our mailing lists. The lists are actively monitored by Stanford's Protégé team, as well as many experienced Protégé users from the community at large. Click the Subscribe button next to the list you wish to join. Please note that you must be subscribed to a list before you can post messages."

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor thanks a lot, okay i did subscribe now and i did send an email to  protege-user@lists.stanford.edu is there a public place (like jena) where we can see the question ? just in order to see their reply

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i sent a message to that mailling list, and one guy said it is a bug, and he submit a ticket https://github.com/protegeproject/ontograf/issues/13

Comment: @Ania there are probably publicly browse able archives of the list,  but it's a mailing list,so you should get replies in your email.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yes i received an email about it, and now i am receiving emails about everything in that mail list, no worries, just hope they will solve it soon. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in protege and this is the ticket to try to solve it

https://github.com/protegeproject/ontograf/issues/13

Comment: I noticed your comment on the ticket.  If you're still looking for a workaround, why not just combine the ontologies into one and load that?

Comment: But none of this answers the question of why this was previously working . How did onto Graf show the content from imported ontologies before, but not now?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor that is what i really don't know, it was working and i wrote about half of the report using it and then it is not working, maybe bty it is not a bug, maybe something else, because it is just one user's opinion and he open a ticket, let's wait for their answer. Plus, yes i am doing now this work arround by making the two ontologies from the same prefix, it is not good at all believe me, but the only option avaiable

Comment: so many other problems, the fuseki reasoners, as you know, not working with owl 2, i have to load more than 10 million triples to protege and then wait for him to extract the inffered triples,  jena stil makes error with distinct and contact group, now new onto graf problem,  .... sql to rdf not nice :) but interesting B-)

Comment: Well,  at least be sure to tell the onto Graf people that *sometimes* individuals from imported ontologies are displayed.